# How to include a sigmajs graph in its corresponding container

Tags: css, html, canvas, sigma.js

I'm trying to draw a graph using **sigma.js**. I'm already done, but the problem is that the graph is not included in the corresponding container.

See the screenshot below:

[image]

This is my html code:

```
<div id="graph">
    <div id="sigma-container">
    </div>
</div>
```

and this is the CSS:

```
#graph {
    position: relative;
    width: 700px;
    min-height: 400px;
    margin-top: 2%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    border: 10px solid #555;
    padding: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #fff;
}

#sigma-container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

then, I generate my graph calling:

```
s = new sigma({ graph: g, container: 'sigma-container' });
```

where `g = { nodes: [1, 2, 3, ...], edges: [1, 2, 3, ...] };`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At present I've solved the problem setting the following in my CSS:

```
.sigma-scene, .sigma-labels, .sigma-mouse {
    left: 0;
}
```